# Proper User of array.reduce()

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I've outlined below a solution to a problem on freeCodeCamp and I want to check my logic/understanding of how array.reduce() works.

```
  function largestOfFour(arr) {

  // Created bigArray[]; as an empty container to push the largest number into.
  var bigArray = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
     bigArray.push(arr[i].reduce(function(a, b) {
     return Math.max(a, b);
     }));
    }
   return bigArray;
  }

  largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```

So, reduce() is calling a function that is returning the Maximum value between a and b.

a is the initial value, and is 0 since I didn't pass an initial value, and 4 would be the current value, which is b.  Obviously 4 is larger that 0 and at that moment, Math.max = 4.

```
then a = 4 and b = 5, then Math.max = 5
then a = 5 and b = 1, then Math.max = 5
then a = 5, and b = 3, then Math.max = 5
```

and after iterating through each number in the array it uses push() to push 5 into the bigArray[].

```
bigArray.push(arr[i].reduce(function(a, b){return Math.max(a, b);}));
//arr[0] is now arr[4, 5, 1, 3]
arr[0].reduce(function(a, b){return Math.max(0, 4);}));
//Math.max returns 4
arr[0].reduce(function(a, b){return Math.max(4, 5);}));
//Math.max returns 5
arr[0].reduce(function(a, b){return Math.max(5, 1);}));
//Math.max returns 5    
arr[0].reduce(function(a, b){return Math.max(5, 3);}));
//Math.max returns 5
```

After the above logic, 5 gets 'push()' into bigArray and bigArray = [5].

Just checking my logic and understanding of my own code.

Comment: Is `arr` an array of arrays?

Comment: It's quite obvious looking at the parameter.

Comment: This would be better suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I missed that last line of the code block

Comment: _"a is the initial value, and is 0 since I didn't pass an initial value"_ That's wrong

Comment: @RyanSpeight, just for the future - there's a cool trick regarding the `Math.max` and `Math.min`. Instead of iterating through the array you can just call it like that: `var maxArrayValue = Math.max.apply({}, [1,4,5,2,6,3])` or if using ES6 `let maxArrayValue = Math.max(...[1,4,5,2,6,3])`.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is your question ?

Comment: `reduce` not only accepts the reducing function that one provides to it as first parameter, it also accepts a second parameter, the very *initial value* of the reducing function ... `arr[i].reduce(function(a, b) { return Math.max(a, b); }, 0)` ... here Zero, which the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Just checking my logic and understanding of my own code.

There is a slight correction required.

In the **First iteration** comparison is not between `0` and `4`, **it is between `4` and `5`**.

Have a look at this **demo**

```js
[4, 5, 1, 3].reduce(function(a, b) {
  console.log(a, b)
  return Math.max(a, b);
})
```

Output is

```
4 5

5 1

5 3
```

So, there are just 3 iterations, have a look at this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=a#How_reduce_works). Number of iterations are **n - 1**, with *n* being the number of items.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks for the clarification.  It's n - 1, or in this case only 3 iterations because 4 and 5 are passed into 'a' and 'b'.